# How to insert correctly content of a table directly in an other table?

Tags: postgresql, select, sql-insert

Good day, I have using Javascript in Mirth Connect to insert all raws that are allocated in a table of PostgreSql database directly in an other table , and in case of duplicate, update the row. I am trying with it,but it gives to me this error:

```
InsertIntoPatientMapping= dbConn.executeUpdate('insert into patient_mapping (select * from patient_mapping_test) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE');
```

```
    Wrapped org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DUPLICATE"  Position: 69
```

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a id column, for upserting considering only the key as duplicate, you can:

```
insert into patient_mapping (select * from patient_mapping_test) ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET id=EXCLUDED.id
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html

#### Edit

There are a couple of things you need to consider for this:

- You need to specify which columns the conflict occurs;
- Each column must have an index;
- You need to specify how to replace the conflicted values.

---

For instance:

```
create table T1 (id integer unique);
create table T2 (id integer unique);
insert into T1 (id) values (1);
insert into T1 (id) values (2);
insert into T2 (id) values (1);
insert into T2 (select * from T1) on conflict (id) do update set id=EXCLUDED.id;

select * from T2;
```

This may help you: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/